# AngularJs. Routing. Handle server request. Few questions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

I have following page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var myModule = angular.module('somename', []);

          myModule.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                    when('/zzz', {templateUrl:'' , controller: TestCtrl}).
                    when('/test1', {template:' ', controller: TestDataCtrl}).
                    when('/test2', {template:'/abc ', controller: function TestCtrl1() {alert("test2")} }).
                    when('/test/:userid', { controller: TestDataCtrl }).
                    when('/users/:userid', {templateUrl: '/users/:userid?html=true', controller: UserDataCtrl}).
                    otherwise({redirectTo: '/works'});

        });

        function TestCtrl($scope) { alert("test") }

        function UserDataCtrl($scope, $http) {
    ...
        }

        function TestDataCtrl($scope, $http, $routeParams, $route) {
          $http.get('users/1').success(function (data) {
            console.log("UserDataCtrl");
            $scope.user = data;
        });

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myModule">
<div ng-view></div>

{{1+1}}
</body>
</html>
```

1)When I navigate to the following url `http://localhost:7000/service/1#/test1`
it is allways sends two requests to server (in my case REST service), something
like `http://localhost:7000/service/1` and `http://localhost:7000/archivarius/users/1`. Can I somehow handle first (useless) browser request, maybe using AngularJs controller? I mean when user enter url `http://localhost:7000/service/1#/test1` the only things (requests) should happen in test2 controller. Is it possible?

2)In routing configuration why do I have to specify either  template or templateUrl? Why I can't just specify only controller for route?

Comment: you have forgotten a comma in this line `when('/zzz', {templateUrl:'' controller: TestCtrl})`, it should be `when('/zzz', {templateUrl:'' , controller: TestCtrl})`

Comment: It is not an issue, I forgot to add when modified sample in text editor. Initially I want to leave only controller part.

Answer (score 1):

You should always trace a code that is syntactically right. in your case you are

1. providing a wrong name for your `ng-app` directive ( at line 2: it should be `ng-app="someoname"` because you module's name is `"somename"`
2. initializing your application more than once:
        you have an `ng-app` at line 2 (`<html lang="en" ng-app="myModule">`) and another one at you `body` tag (`<body ng-app="myModule">`)

you may trace your app's logical flow after dealing with these syntactical problems.

Comment: Thank you for reply! There is no problem with naming, names are the same. I just changed before posting and forgot to sync. There is no problems with naming.

Answer (score 0):

You may be see two http request because $http.get('users/1') and for the templateUrl 
in '/users/:userid' route.

In routing configuration you should specify template or templateUrl and one controller for route.

Bye

Comment: So as I understood there is always request for template or templateUrl, right? Even for /zzz route, where I only want to show alert msg? It is related to my 2-nd question -- why can't I specify only controller for route?

Comment: no only for templateUrl.I don't really know if you can set route without any template ^^ but imo you could use a directive in that case. Why do you want to set more than one controller for route ? and all in all imo it smells like a bad design.

Comment: No, I want to set only on controller, without any templates, so I can handle some route within some action only on client. I don't know whether it is possible, but is seems that without specifying template(url) it won't work...